# How to reorder the autoincremet key in mysql

Tags: mysql, primary-key, sql-insert, auto-increment

I need to insert a new row after the `Id` `1` and re-arrange the keys .

How its possible ???
Thank You .

**Table**

```
    Id | Latitude | Longitude
    ---+----------+-----------
    1    10.111     11.111
    2    10.333     11.333
    3    10.444     11.444
    4    10.555     11.555
```

**Expected Table**

```
        Id | Latitude | Longitude
        ---+----------+-----------
        1    10.111     11.111
        2    10.222     11.222
        3    10.333     11.333
        4    10.444     11.444
        5    10.555     11.555
```

Comment: Why? The id is simply a unique reference. You can order result by Latitude and Longitude (*and you should not be assuming that rows will be ordered without using an order by clause*).

Comment: No I can't. There is another option in my google map- I can select two points and delete, all the points between that two will be delete

Comment: What does that have to do with the id? geo points are defined by lat/long not the db's primary key

Comment: "select two points and delete, all the points between that two" -- that's a two dimensional (well probably even three dimensional taking the earths spherical shape into account) task you cannot simply map to one dimension like that.

Comment: @Used_By_Already Thanks for the support. I will discuss it with my team and I will update the question

Comment: @Used_By_Already : I need to mark the points in map and draw the travelling path in order, If I insert the new row in last i cant draw the correct path.